# Javascript RegExp for exact multiple words with special characters match

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, regex, frontend

I'm using RegExp for multiple words match. It has dynamic values so when a special character like "(" comes it takes that as an expression and shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression error.

```js
let text = 'working text and (not working text'
let findTerm = ['working text', '(not working text']
let replaceFromRegExp = new RegExp('\\b'+`(${findTerm.join("|")})`+'\\b', 'g')
text = text.replace(replaceFromRegExp, match => "<mark>" + match + "</mark>")
console.log(text)
```

Comment: Your text contains a special regex character `(`. If you want all the texts to be literal, try [escaping them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) matches any of the following three positions:

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.
   You need universal word boundaries that will require a non-word char or start of string before a search word, and a non-word char or end of string after a search string.

Note you need to also sort the `findTerm` items in the descending order by length to avoid overlapping term issues.

Finally, do not forget to escape the `findTerm` items to be used in a regex pattern.

You can use

```js
let text = 'working text and (not working text'
let findTerm = ['working text', '(not working text']
findTerm.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
let replaceFromRegExp = new RegExp(String.raw`(?!\B\w)(?:${findTerm.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|")})(?!\B\w)`, 'g')
console.log(replaceFromRegExp)
text = text.replace(replaceFromRegExp, "<mark>$&</mark>")
console.log(text)
```

Note that `"<mark>$&</mark>"` is a shorter way of saying `match => "<mark>" + match + "</mark>"`, as `$&` is a backreference to the whole match value in a string replacement pattern.

The regex is

```js
/(?!\B\w)(?:\(not working text|working text)(?!\B\w)/g
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBIcoW/3). *Details*:

- `(?!\B\w)` - either a non-word boundary if the next char is not a word char, or a word boundary if the next char is a word char
- `(?:\(not working text|working text)` - a non-capturing group matching one of the alternative patterns set in the `findTerm` array
- `(?!\B\w)` - either a non-word boundary if the next char is not a word char, or a word boundary if the next char is a word char

Comment: It works. If we don't want whole word exact match,  just remove the \b in this RegExp.

Comment: @PyRu Actually, if you do not need an exact match, remove `(?:\B(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))` and `(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w)\B)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accpeted