# Multiword RegEx containing '/' is not correctly finding the term

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hey there I'm trying to write a multi-word RegEx that uses word boundaries. The string I'm searching is as follows (this is only a test string):

`const regString = "/gamma/ truck?timer!doctor\\face"`

Here is my regular expression:

`const testReg2 = new RegExp("\\b\/gamma/|truck|\\?|face\\b", "gi");`

For whatever reason the console posts `['truck', '?', 'face']` but it refuses to find '/gamma/' which is puzzling because `const testReg = new RegExp("/gamma/");` does find '/gamma/'.

```js
const regString = "/gamma/ truck?timer!doctor\\face"
const testReg2 = new RegExp("\\b\/gamma/|truck|\\?|face\\b", "gi");

console.log(regString.match(testReg2))
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `|\\?|` ?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski OK but I don't see the reason for the *options* `|`

Comment: The reason for \\? was because I assumed you had to escape the '?' because it is used in regular expressions for lookahead/behind "?=" or "?<=" is this correct? Also I used the '|' because I had seen this in other multi-word expressions posted online.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, you indeed needed to match that `?`. Thanks for clarifying, I thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in using `\b\/gamma` and expecting it to match `"/gamma"` (same for the closing `\b`).

The Word Boundary `\b` in order to work it should be followed (or preceded, depending on where it's used) by at least one (or more) Word characters. Which is not — due to the non-word `/` character.

To visualize, let's spread those characters:

```
# Regex: \bxyz

/ g a m m a
 ^--------- \b points here. Match: `gamma`

# Regex: \b\/xyz

/ g a m m a
\b points nowhere. Match: none since `/` is a non-word char
```

Either: remove the `\/` since that's already a specific character prefix / suffix, or...

If you really *need* to make sure the exact existance and sequence of those characters `/gamma/`, than don't use `\b` for the */gamma/* case.

```
\/gamma\/|\b(truck|\?|face)\b
```

[Example on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KnLfNH/1)

```js
const regString = "/gamma/ truck?timer!doctor\\face"

console.log(regString.match(/\/gamma\/|\b(truck|\?|face)\b/gi))
```

Comment: OP wanted to match `/gamma/` not `gamma`. They probably didn't know that `\b` doesn't always work on the beginning of the string.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski your statement is wrong. Neither I suggested anything about `gamma` I was just focusing on the first `/` in `/gam...` to make a valid point. And why do you think `\b`  *"doesn't always work on the beginning of a string"*?  https://regex101.com/r/Lmd1qQ/1

Comment: Ah thank you I actually just starting reading up on \b and began to see the problem, I assumed it just captured a whole word or similar without any additional characters. But now I understand it captures \w up until the next \W. I see now it isn't even useful for what I needed, sorry.

Comment: @Slakemoth the rule of thumbs is just to: **Don't** use non-word characters right after `\b` - it makes no sense. :) There's no word boundary between a `\b` and a `/` (or any other non-word char)

Comment: Thank you I understand that alot better now, I completely misunderstood how ```\b``` worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make this work, a) using word boundaries with words that start/end with word chars only (when the words are know beforehand, it is the easiest way), or b) using [adaptive dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467672/3832970) (this is good if your "word" list is dynamic, or user-defined).

Here is **Option 1**:

```js
const regString = "/gamma/ truck?timer!doctor\\face"
const testReg2 = /\/gamma\/|\?|\b(?:truck|face)\b/gi;
console.log(regString.match(testReg2))
```

So, here, `?` and `/gamma/` are NOT checked if they are whole words or not, since they start/end with non-word chars.

Now, **Option 2**:

```js
const regString = "/gamma/ truck?timer!doctor\\face";
const words = ["/gamma/", "?", "truck", "face"];
const testReg2 = new RegExp("(?!\\B\\w)(?:" + words.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|") + ")(?<!\\w\\B)", "gi");
console.log(regString.match(testReg2));
```

This solution requires the lookbehind support, but it makes sure the whole word check is applied only in case there are word chars at the start/end of the word (also, all special chars are escaped appropriately).

Answer (score -1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756/5089567)

> [...] at the beginning or end of a string if it begins or ends (respectively) with a word character ([0-9A-Za-z_])

Your string doesn't start with `[0-9A-Za-z_]` hence not match